# Is it possible to catch 'Execution exception' in Java Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to somehow catch the 'Execution exception' which is normally shown in browser. I just don't like the fact that I have to validate data manually, when they seem to be validated by Play anyway.
For example I would like to catch exceptions like the one below.

> [IllegalStateException: Error(s) binding form: {"email":["Valid email
>   required"]}]

It appears after `User user = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();` in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalStateException` is a runtime exception and is not meant to be caught.
Replace your code with:

```
Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
if(userForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest();
} else {
    User user = userForm.get();
    // whatever
    return ok();
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Forgot to add generic.

Comment: What about '[RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]'? Can I do something with them? Would be grateful for quick answer.

Comment: `Error while committing the transaction` sounds like a serious `SQL` exception. Look for hints in stacktraces in console.

Comment: It is SQL exception. Happens after 'JPA.em().persist(userForm.get());' when the user already exists. I just don't know if I can somehow catch an exception like that, or I have to manually check if user already exists in my database before calling 'persist(userForm.get())'. How would You solve this?

Comment: In both scenarios there are gotchas. You could take an optimistic approach and just try to insert a user, catch the exception and return bad request response. If you want to check if user already exists - do it from transaction, otherwise you will receive exception like in first approach.

Comment: I just don't know how to 'catch the exception and return bad request response' in this optimistic approach. Typical try-catch block does not help as the exception seems to be thrown in some other thread.
Could You also explain how to do this 'from transaction'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82218/discussion-between-mon-calamari-and-user59600).